# Issues going from UTF-8 to Windows Latin1 and back

Tags: encoding, fasttext

I am working within a rather complicated system where data is entered by a respondent and stored in an xml file that uses UTF-8 encoding. That data is then uploaded to an Oracle database that uses latin1 encoding which is causing strange characters to show up such as upside down question marks for a small percentage of our data (~0.01%) that type non-Latin characters. I then take this data and build NLP models using fasttext (which expects UTF-8) data.

Obviously there are an abundance of issues here. My first question is what are the ramifications of feeding fasttext a file in latin1 when it is expecting UTF-8? For example, I might have a response that shows up on my database as:

```
HE'S
```

If I read this file in R but tell it the encoding is UTF-8 it then shows up as

```
HE<U+0092>S
```

Is fasttext essentially doing the same thing? Will fasttext read it as one word with 11 characters?

I am trying to convince my database administrators it is worthwhile switching our Oracle database to UTF-8 but they just see only 0.01% of characters showing up as upside down question marks and think it isn't worth the risk. I guess my question is, its more far reaching than just upside down question marks in this situation right?

A second question is, we no longer have the original xml files in UTF-8 that the database was populated using, is it possible to revert back from the latin1 database we have to UTF-8 without them?

Comment: Only ask one question per question. If you want to know how fasttext reacts to non-UTF-8 files then ask that question (and all the commentary about Oracle is irrelevant). If you want to know about converting database encodings then ask about that (and all the commentary about fasttext is irrelevant). But don't ask about both in the same question.

Comment: You don't appear to have any Latin1 text. 0x92 is a [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) character equivalent to [U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_single_quotation_mark). U+0092 isn't really valid Unicode, it's an undefined control character, but [Latin1 is treated like Windows-1252 in certain circumstances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). If you convert your text from Windows-1252 to UTF-8 before storing it in the database I suspect it will work.

Comment: Maybe I am incorrect and the database isn't actually Latin1 but Windows-1252. I thought they were equivalent. In either case converting the text from Windows-1252 to UTF-8 before storing on the database isn't possible as the data originates as UTF-8 but then gets put on a Windows-1252 database

Comment: You know well: there is only one solution: you must convert the field to a unicode data. Having utf-8 data and putting as is as a different encoding is just wrong, and it will give you many problems. Unicode allow smooth transition (changing any piece of the stack), but you should never cheat (faking an encoding). Sorting, searching, etc. will have problems. And it is not difficult to change encoding of a column (and for huge databases which must be 100% online, there are many tricks: e.g. second column: you read, if it is NULL you read the original, until you converted all).